# Ambiguity in ANSI C YACC grammar

Tags: c, grammar, yacc

I'm watching ANSI C YACC grammar.
And there is something that I don't understand.
http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#expression

```
assignment_expression
    : conditional_expression
    | unary_expression assignment_operator assignment_expression
    ;

constant_expression
    : conditional_expression
    ;
```

Here are the rules for assignment expression and constant expression.
My question is that how can they both use `conditional_expression` to reduce?
If there is a token reduced to a conditional_expression, after the token reduced how does YACC parser know how to reduce the token next between `assignment_expression` and `constant_expression`?
I think I'm missing something huge but I can't find that by myself.
Thank you

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I just edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ambiguity because there is no context in which both `assignment_expression` and `constant_expression` may appear.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with having rules of the form

```
a: z;
b: z;
c: z;
```

if `a`, `b`, and `c` all appear in different contexts. If you have the following

```
t: a | b | c;
```

then there's a problem. But there's nothing like that for `conditional_expression`.

Answer (score 2):

A EBNF grammar can have multiple valid rules/states at the same time.That means in this case if it finds a conditional it can match an assignment_expression and a constant_expression at the same time. To get an unique answer the rules using these two rules must be specific enough to match a given input sequence only to a single sequence of rules or you can use priorities to select a single sequence of rules from multiple possible sequences.